# Activating unlocked iPhone 4s with SIM but without contract?

Tags: iphone, sim

I'm in a research lab where we're looking to get an iPhone 4s to use as a speedier iPod touch.  We don't want a cell phone contract, and we want to avoid jailbreaking or borrowing a SIM card just for activation (unless it's the only option).

When purchasing the unlocked iPhone, there are options for 'No SIM' and 'T-Mobile SIM (without contract)'.  Searching the internet has shown that unlocking without a SIM isn't possible.  If we get the T-Mobile SIM, will we be able to activate even without a contract ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the T-Mobile SIM it will only activate the device, it will not create a contract.  If you feel safe you can get it without a SIM, head over to the closest Apple Store and ask them to activate the phones using AT&T dummy cards.

Once you activate the phones, I suggest putting the phones in airplane mode and turn on Wifi, otherwise the phone will constantly be searching for signal which will cause the battery to drain.

Good luck.